# How to have a select list pop out of an input box?

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, list, custom-component

I'm creating an html5/js app for iPad via phonegap. I'd like to implement a search input box such that the results of the search appear in a select list that pops out of the box (sort of like the popover in ios sdk).  I want it to work similarly to the way the google search bar looks in the iPad safari browser.

I can't find anything that could make this happen.  I was thinking about putting the select list behind the input box by using a CSS style position:absolute... But you can see it (and click on it) behind the search bar.  It's got to be native ui.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Use html5 <datalist> or any jquery autocomplete plugin.

Comment: The jquery plugins that I see don't support native ui.

Comment: [What do you mean that you can't do it with a select list behind the input box?](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/LLBgh/)

Comment: I meant that my efforts to do so (which I suspected was the solution) didn't produce a workable solution.  Yours is perfect though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML ->

```
<div class="select">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="theText" />   
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <select>
      <option value="1"> One </option>
      <option value="2"> Two </option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS ->

```
.select{
  border:1px solid rgb(230,230,230);
  width:165px;
  height:25px;  
  position:relative;
  background:;    
}
.input-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
    top:0;
  width:135px;  
  height:25px;
  overflow:hidden;  
  z-index:10;
}
input{
  border:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:135px;    
}
.options{
  position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:-2px;
  display:none;
  width:164px;
  border-top:none;  
  background:#fff;
  z-index:0;    
}
.options select{
  width:189px;
  min-height:26px;  
  border:1px solid rgb(230,230,230);    
}
```

A little jQuery flavor ->

```
$('.select input').on('keyup', function(){
  $('.options').show();
});
$('select').on('change', function(){
  $('.options').hide();
});
```